# How to separate Video campaigns from Display campaigns in Google Analytics via the PHP API

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-ads-api

I'm using the PHP API to pull in data from analytics and separating out the results via the display and google search like so:

```
ga:adDistributionNetwork=@Content
```

and for search:

```
ga:adDistributionNetwork=@Google Search
```

The problem is the ad distribution network for content is putting together all the Display campaign results and Video campaign results into one calculation under content.

In adwords this data is separated as expected:

[image]

In Google Analytics the data is only split via search and display but display includes the video data as well.

[image]

Doe's anyone know how to separate the data in Google Analytics, therefore, being able to access the data via the API?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is the [`ga:istrueviewvideoad`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=adwords&jump=ga_istrueviewvideoad) dimension, which to my knowledge is [the only AdWords video-related dimension/metric available via the GA API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=adwords).

If this doesn't include all video content, it seems your workaround would be to include a keywords (eg `"vid"`) in your campaigns or ad groups and filter based on that keyword.